# Making this function more like C++ and less like C

Tags: c++

I have this function which opens /dev/urand and reads into a pointer of size; however it's very C like and not very C++ like. I want to make the function look more like modern C++.

```
void URand::getrandom(uint64_t* r,uint8_t s){
    FILE* f = fopen("/dev/urandom","rb");
    assert(f);
    
    switch (s) {
        case 8:
            fread(r,sizeof(uint8_t),1,f);
            break;
        case 16:
            fread(r,sizeof(uint16_t),1,f);
            break;
        case 32:
            fread(r,sizeof(uint32_t),1,f);
            break;
        case 64:
            fread(r,sizeof(uint64_t),1,f);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    fclose(f);
}
```

So the first issue is I'm passing uint64_t if I might not even need a variable of that size , if I only need 1 byte then I should pass in uint8, or 2 bytes then uint16.
The other is I'm passing in the number of bits needed to be read. Can this be automated?
Can I for example pass in the type(uint8_t) as an argument itself so the function knows which type its dealing with and the size its dealing with? I can't do sizeof(r) because r is a pointer.

Maybe function overloading could be a solution where I have a different type for each argument?

```
void URand::getrandom(uint8_t* r);
void URand::getrandom(uint16_t* r);
void URand::getrandom(uint32_t* r);
void URand::getrandom(uin64_t* r);
```

I get that's a more pleasant solution than what I have; however I think with modern C++ it could be done even nicer and cleaner.

Comment: If you want to make the code more like modern C++, then you should probably use [`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) instead of `fopen` and `fread`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks, what about the function arguments and types?

Comment: The question is probably better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ if you have working code.

Comment: The `/dev/urandom` has a very limited amount of entropy.  It's good for getting a seed value.  It's not so good as a random number generator if you are getting a lot of random numbers (more than, say, a dozen).

Comment: @Eljay Okay, I'll remove /dev/urandom and use std::random_device. I assumed for cryptographically secure random you should use /dev/random which can stall in the case there is no more entropy where /dev/urandom can continue generating random numbers only less secure

Comment: I don't think it stalls, rather the randomness becomes less randomy.  (Not using the technical terms.)  Your best bet is to use the [pseudo-random number generators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that are part of C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Modern" C++ would not open /dev/urandom, but use the std library. Have a look at `https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random`, particularly the `random_device`.

Also it would use templates to solve your size (uint8_t ... uint64_t) problem.

So something like this would be "modern".

```
template <typename Value>
Value getrandom(Value &v)
{
   std::random_device rd;
   std::uniform_int_distribution<Value> dist(0, std::numeric_limits<Value>::max());
   v = dist(rd);
   return v;
}
```

where `std::numeric_limits<Value>::max()` returns the maximum possible value for `Value`.

Even more modern C++ would probably use template contraints and concepts to ensure that `Value` is an unsigned integer value.

Comment: So does numeric_limits<Value>::Max means it would generate the maximum value for that specific type? Eg: 255 for uint8_t?

Comment: Yes. std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max()  returns 255.

Comment: `#include <random>`

Answer (score 4):

I would probably do something like this:

```
template<typename Unsigned>
Unsigned dev_urandom()
{
    Unsigned u;
    std::ifstream("/dev/urandom", std::ios::binary).read((char*)&u, sizeof(u));
    return u;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << dev_urandom<unsigned int>() << '\n';
}
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
template<typename Unsigned>
void dev_urandom(Unsigned& u)
{
    std::ifstream("/dev/urandom", std::ios::binary).read((char*)&u, sizeof(u));
}

int main()
{
    unsigned u;
    dev_urandom(u);
    std::cout << u << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I actually like that you can explicitly request the type to be unsigned int here. The other solution presented using random_device , which also works but I'll combine the two. Using random device and your function type.

Comment: This code is _not_ requesting the type to be `unsigned`. It just names the template parameter `Unsigned`, but this name does nothing.

Comment: If you really want to require this, you need a `required` clause, probably something like `requires(std::is_unsigned<Unsigned>)`. That's template meta programming and part of C++20.

Comment: @HajoKirchhoff Yes, indeed. It's just a hint to the caller to use unsigned types.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void getrandom(T* r){
  std::ifstream f("/dev/urandom", std::ios::binary);
  f.read(r, sizeof(*r));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in a lot of way, and another solution is that you can create class Handler and define it's operator() , use it in std::map.

minimal example for start:

```cpp
void getrandom(uint64_t* r, uint8_t s)
{
    FILE* f = fopen("/dev/urandom", "rb");
    assert(f);

    static auto handlers = std::map<uint8_t, std::function<size_t()>>{
        {8, [f, r]() -> size_t { return fread(r, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, f); }},
        {16, [f, r]() -> size_t { return fread(r, sizeof(uint16_t), 1, f); }},
        {32, [f, r]() -> size_t { return fread(r, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, f); }},
        {64, [f, r]() -> size_t { return fread(r, sizeof(uint64_t), 1, f); }}};
    handlers[s]();
    fclose(f);

    ;
}
```